# How can I send some parameters to API without link?

Tags: php

I will try to explain what I need. I am using `API` of some website that sends `message` to `phone number`. When user writes his `phone number` into the form of my website, the data is sent to another website. I want the data to be sent without opening `new window` or `link`. Is it possible? Let the link be `"example.com?number=123456789".`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using AJAX technology?

> AJAX is a developers dream, because you can:  Update a web page
>   without reloading the page    Request data from a server - after the
>   page has loaded   Receive data from a server - after the page has
>   loaded    Send data to a server - in the background

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/